# Possibility of bluetooth mesh implementation on windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt, bluetooth-mesh

I'm looking for way to implement a part of bluetooth mesh features ( using WinRt. I'm wondering if it's possible to create my own adv packages with it.

The only thing i found was ManufacturerData class but it's not the thing, isn't it? The second thing is using GATT, which seems doable. Is there some kind of workaround or should i concentrate on GATT?

Comment: The [`BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher) can be used to create custom advertisement packages, with some limitations. Is that sufficient for your use case?

Comment: My goal is to implement bluetooth mesh library (i need to do provision and to emulate node functionality) over the WinRt library.  As far as i know BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher only allows to manage flags and manufacturer data which doesn't seem enough. I'm researching WinRt but if there is some other particularly windows library i would be glad to look it up.

Comment: I talked with Bluetooth Team, currently Windows does not support public APIs to implement Bluetooth mesh. Could you please provide more information about your needs? What is the scenario in which you want to use this, then we might be able to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: I want to create a simple ble mesh node emulator and a provisioner application. I found that advertize packages can be modified with custom data section. Emulator should have generic ON\OFF server (to emulate light switch) and generic level server (to emulate light sensor). Provision app should apply provision to emulator and esp32 node.  @JunjieZhu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked with Bluetooth Team about your scenario and purpose of creating a simple BLE mesh node emulator and configurator program, but there is no UWP documented API to implement Bluetooth mesh.